# Enable submit button on checkbox click

Tags: javascript

This should be simple, but I'm missing something.

I am creating a form which asks users to accept terms and conditions and would like to disable the submit button until they click the checkbox, but can't get it to work (I'm not great at javascript)

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/timothylarson/NEE3V/4/

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" onchange="checked('accept')" /> I HAVE READ AND ACCEPT THE <a href="">TERMS & CONDITIONS</a></p>
    <br/>
    <input disabled="disabled" type="button" id="accept" class="button-grey" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function checked(accept) {
    var myLayer = document.getElementById(accept);
    var input = myLayer.childNodes[0];
    if (input.checked == true) {
        myLayer.class = "button-orange";
        myLayer.disabled = "";
    } else {
        myLayer.class = "button-grey";
        myLayer.disabled = "disabled";
    };
}
```

CSS:

```
p {
    font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.button-orange {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #321;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #999;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #E74700;
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-top:22px;
    padding-bottom:22px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    margin-top:-4px;
    font-weight:700;
}
.button-orange:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
.button-grey {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #321;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #999;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #999;
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-top:22px;
    padding-bottom:22px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    margin-top:-4px;
    font-weight:700;
}
```

Comment: You should really use [minimal, complete, tested and readable code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your question. You need almost *none* of that CSS to demonstrate the problem (just enough to show a contrast between the two classes, with perhaps a background-color, would be enough).

Comment: This ought to be in a fiddle if you can, with light code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code a some issues like this

1- To change the class you need use `className` property not the `class`
2- `mLayer` is a button element. So there is no child element presents

```
var input = myLayer.childNodes[0];
```

here `input` will not the `checkbox` element and thus your code won't work.

3- Changed the function name as well `checked` is reserved.

I have made above correction in your code. So try this

```
function checkedChanged(element) {

    var myLayer = document.getElementById('accept');
    if (element.checked == true) {
        myLayer.className = "button-orange";
        myLayer.disabled = "";
    } else {
        myLayer.className = "button-grey";
        myLayer.disabled = "disabled";
    };
}
```

Change Checkbox markup with this

```
<input type="checkbox" value="checkbox" onchange="checkedChanged(this)" />
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NEE3V/6/)

Comment: Interesting, but shouldn't `disabled` be a Boolean (`true`/`false`)?

Comment: @DavidThomas in HTML5, `<input type="text" disabled />` is valid. in XHTML `<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />` is also valid. So there is no need of `true/false`.

Comment: My point precisely, which is why I'm wondering why you've used `myLayer.disabled = ""` and `myLayer.disabled = "disabled"`? Your approach *works*, so I have no problem with it, I am, though, curious as to why you chose that approach.

Comment: That helps to remove the `disabled` attribute from the element. If you  see the console and do check/uncheck, you can see the desired change in markup.

Answer (score 1):

At first if you disable button you should remove this line from CSS .button-grey class

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Second, instead of using inline event handler, would be better if you use `addEventListener`

```
function checked(e) {
    var submit = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
    // since checkbox is unchecked by default there's no need to check if is checked
    submit.classList.toggle("button-grey");
    submit.classList.toggle("button-orange");
    submit.disabled = !submit.disabled;
}

var chkBox = document.getElementById("chkBox");

chkBox.addEventListener("change", checked);
```

[***Demonstration***](http://jsfiddle.net/kE43g/)

---

I also made some changes to your HTML:

1. Remove inline event handler from checkbox and add id to `chkBox`;
2. Change button type to submit and id to `btnSubmit`.